# Word for Mac styles are not being retained and look weird after saving them

Tags: microsoft-word, styles

I'm using Word for Mac 16.43; I have a master template I use for documentation, and created a new document with it. If I modify elements like heading and table of contents, and save the document, next time I open it I often find they've been changed.

Not reverted to their original values, but weird stuff added like small caps and hanging indents. On the styles, "add to quick style list" is checked, "add to template" and "automatically update" are off. I've been using Word forever and thought I was pretty good at styles, but this is driving me nuts.

Comment: What is the MacOS version that you are running? Is your 16.43 version of Office fully updated?

Comment: Yes, Word is 16.43. OS is 11.0.1, and the problems may have started when I recently updated to Big Sur. I've done a lot of Googling on this, the consensus is it may be related to Big Sur. Apple says to contact Microsoft, Microsoft blames Apple. One suggestion was to reboot in safe mode, which can fix font issues, but my problem is styles are getting clobbered.

Comment: I understand a bunch of patches are coming in 16.44 next week that are specific for issues  related to Big Sur. If you want to try it now, you can Check for Update under Help and then use the Advanced button on the Check for Update dialog and join the Insider "Preview" level. Read the Insider agreement statement before doing this.

Comment: Thanks Rich; I applied the 16.44, but when I modify a style and save the document, the updated style is not there. Should I report this to Microsoft, and if so, what would be the best way?

Comment: On Word's Help menu select Feedback and then I Don't Like Something. It goes to the Development Team. Professionalism of your response counts.